# Symfony2 return null entities only in production

Tags: php, database, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a very strange problem. I have a database with differents fields. If I do `doctrine:schema:update` or `doctrine:schema:validate` all is right.

But if I add a new field in my entity, then I do `doctrine:schema:update` there aren't any problems, but if I write a value in these new fields. In development environment all is right, but in production environment:

`$entity->getNewfield()` always return null. and `$entity->setNewfield("test")` works fine in dev but in production doesn't persist.

Anybody knows what could be the problem?

Comment: It seems to me, that you should try to clear your cache. :)

Comment: As fperet said, try to clear your cache with `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: You should do [this](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/keep-calm-and-clear-cache-11.png)

Comment: Of course I clear my cache and warm up, and remove all the cache but this isn't the problem.

Comment: Have you checked `error.log` file?

Comment: you may have cache on entities, try to restart apache / nginx or php-fpm OR clear your apc cache with `php -r "apc_clear_cache(); apc_clear_cache('user'); apc_clear_cache('opcode');"`